# Cant execute Socket.on('connect',function(){}) for the second time in same page

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to create a simple app with simple logout and login. While logging in am joining the room and while logout am leaving the room with socket.leave('room');

Problem is that if i login again in the same page without refresh, the code inside the socket.on('connect',...) s not getting executing. Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: consider changing it to "on join" or something (custom message). connect is used by infrastructure of socket.io on connecting to websockets backend.

Comment: Some code is needed to answer correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jakub said, the 'connect' event fires when the client makes a connection to the server, not on joining a room. Rooms are an extra namespace on top of the connection. If you want to execute code every time someone joins, the simplest way would be to just have that code run after the `socket.join('whatever')` call is made.

A bit trickier, though perhaps more encompassing solution would be to attach a handler of some sort for joining a room. I'm not sure off hand if you can do `socket.on('join', fn)` but give it a shot. If it doesn't work, you should be able to subscribe via the back-end, something like this might work:

```
socket.manager.store.subscribe('join', function (id, room) {
    //do whatever
});
```